# Ionic 2 + Firebase issue wrong redirect

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I just start developing hybrid apps using Ionic2 and Angular2. 
I decide to use Firebase with AngularFire2, following this tutorial:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md

Everything works fine when I type ionic serve in terminal.
But when I run with ionic run -l and try to open in browser, it redirects me to Firebase Console. Meanwhile on iOS simulator, the project runs perfectly.

Can somebody help me to resolve this issue?

Also, recommend me some hosting to deploy apps with Ionic 2 and Firebase.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a starter-kit for Ionic 2, Angular 4 and Firebase 3.

You can check it out here:
https://github.com/Temeteron/ionic2-firebase-starter-kit

I am not really sure what causes your problem. I encourage you to check this starter-kit, maybe Angular 4 will solve this problem.

About the hosting, this tutorial is deployed on app-engine of Google: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/

A have also deployed there, other web applications, either developed on polymer or Ionic 2. I will put the links below, so you can check out the speed of the response and of the connection that app-engine provides freely.

GitCV: https://www.gitcv.com/

Any Counter: https://any-counter.appspot.com/

Best of luck!